# Find a sufficient statistic.

Tags: estimation, parameter-estimation

Suppose that $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ is a random sample from a distribution with pdf

$$ f(x;\theta)=\frac{\theta^3}{2}x^2e^{-\theta x}, \quad 0<x<\infty$$

where $0<\theta<\infty$

Find a sufficient statistic for $\theta$.

I would appreciate an simple explanation of sufficiency using this example.

Comment: But first, what have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Fisher factorization is as follows:
$$
\underbrace{\left(\frac{\theta^3} 2 \right)^n e^{-\theta\sum_{i=1}^n x_i}}_\text{(A)} \,\,\,\underbrace{\left(\prod_{i=1}^n x_i^2\right)}_\text{(B)}
$$
Factor $\text{(A)}$ depends on $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ only through their sum. Factor $\text{B}$ does not depend on $\theta.$

Comment: The solution provided by our prof states shows the same approach and states that therefore the sufficient statistic is $$  Y = \sum_{i=1}^n X_i$$Why is that ?

Comment: @user1607 Do you know the *Factorisation theorem*? It is an application of that.

Comment: @StubbornAtom just learned about it. I got it now. Thanks !

Comment: @user1607 : Note that you can "accept" an answer.